# MongoDB with the Spark connector

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, sharding, in-memory-database

If I have a replica set with mongodb, than a primary server is receiving all the wirte/read operations and writing them to the server.
The secondary server are reading the operations from the oplog and replicating them.
 Now I would like to analyze the data in mongodb replica set with spark-mongodb-connector. I can install a spark cluster on all three nodes and run analytics on it in memory.
I understand that spark cluster has a master node where I have to submit the spark job for analytics, or spark streaming. Both are installed on an application server in tomcat.

now I need to choose a master node to submit the job from my tomcat app server to the spark cluster.
Should the Primary Server be the Spark Master node? and than the driver of an application can connect to submit jobs on it?.
What would be the Spark master in a sharded cluster?

Comment: can explain your question with more details ?

Comment: does my explanation help

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter which node is the Spark Master in your cluster.
The Spark master will be responsible for assigning the tasks to the Spark executors, it will not receive all read/write requests.
Each executor will then be responsible for fetching the data it needs to process.

Be careful about data partitioning in Spark, it might happen that mongoDB only provides a single partition to start with, so you might want to do a `repartition` first.

Comment: will the spark executors fetch the data from mongodb on the node where it is running based on the submit from an application server spark job from a spark client?

Comment: It depends on how the spark-mongodb-connector is implemented. If it is open source, you can take a look.
But that's generally the desired behaviour for an input connector dealing with data that is already distributed across a cluster.